# Starting trouble

Tags: honda, starting, accord, starter

04 Honda Accord EX doesn't start. Only the dash board lights up when turning the ignition. While nothing happens with the engine.

A few days prior, I took the car to Advance auto store...ran battery, alternator, and starter tests. The conclusion of all that was everything tested good. Hours prior to the tests, I had starting problems; but the car somehow managed to start and I immediately drove it to Advance auto.

After all the tests came back good, the tech person did a drain test  (of the battery). That test resulted in a reading of 1.50 amps with everything off/disconnected and the car in park. So as a temp solution until I get it to a mechanic, I would leave the battery disconnected while parked until I drive it again. I've been driving several days now and as of this morning, I go to reconnect the battery and start the car...and got nothing! Whassup Doc?!

Comment: Do you hear anything when you try to start and 'nothing' happens- is there a whirring or soft clicking noise?

Comment: Aye thanks MooseLucifer...but No there was no whirring /clicking noise

Comment: I was thinking the same as Steve's answer.. When you turn the key to start the engine, does everything turn off (air/radio/lights) like it should, then turn back on when you release the key?

Answer (score 1):

The start motor solenoid can start to work intermittently. Sounds like this could be the case for you.

Try starting the car by going from "on" to "start" repeatedly until you hear the starter engage. This just keeps powering up that solenoid.

If you hear a click when doing this.. That is a working solenoid, and indicates a flat battery. I don't think this is what's happening in your case though. So just try turning to "start" repeatedly.

It can become "stuck" and i had success tapping it with the handle of a hammer before.. This will need someone holding the key to the start position for you.

Comment: IDTOT...with the repeated on to start tactic. Thanks! But the clacking on the starter was to no avail.